# How to create usage and health data service application using powershell

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, monitoring

How to create usage and health data service application using powershell and with existing wss_logging database.

Comment: did my answer below help you?

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this:

a. At the PowerShell prompt, type the following and press Enter:

```
New-SPUsageApplication -Name "Usage and Health Data Collection"
```

b. At the PowerShell prompt, type the following and press Enter:

```
$proxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | where {$_.TypeName -eq "Usage and Health Data Collection Proxy"}
```

c. At the prompt, type the following and press Enter:

```
$proxy.Provision()
```

If it helps you, or maybe is exactly the answer please give it a vote up or mark it as the answer.